# Run script when angular element's children have completed linking

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to know the best way to structure this simple angularJS scenario.

I have a `<div>` which contains two other `<div>`s. When the DOM is ready, I use a [jQuery splitter plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/splitter/) to make the two children sizable.

In plain old HTML, this is no problem! It looks something like this:

```
    <div id="container">
        <div id="leftPane">...</div>
        <div id="rightPane">...</div>
    </div>

    <script>
    $('#container').split('horizontal');
    </script>
```

Now I want to turn components into AngularJS directives, and I'm running into a problem. Here's the root HTML template:

```
    <div id="container" ng-controller="containerCtrl">
        <left-pane></left-pane>
        <right-pane></right-pane>
    </div>
```

Where `leftPane` and `rightPane` are directives something like:

```
app.directive('leftPane', function(){
  return {
    templateUrl: 'leftPane.html',
    replace: true
  }
});
```

With `leftPane.html`:

```
<div id="leftPane"></div>
```

And the container controller:

```
app.controller('containerCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $('#container').split('horizontal');
}]);
```

The problem is that at the time the `.split()` call happens, the child panels have not been compiled and evaluated yet.

Where / how should I call `.split()` to ensure that the children have been evaluated and are in the DOM properly?

---

*** UPDATE: Here is a Plunker demonstrating the issue: http://plnkr.co/edit/idODF0ztbqip44rfsZsE?p=preview

Interestingly there is no issue when using literal templates (`template:'<div>left panel</div>'`). The issue arises when using `templateUrl`. I guess `templateUrl` is evaluated in a different order?

The easiest way to tell what's happening is to look at the DOM while resizing the splitter. You can see the plugin is dynamically setting `width`. But it is not attached to the left panel. At the time the plugin is initialized, the left pane hasn't been added to the DOM yet.

Comment: Its a bad idea to do DOM manipulation in controller. However you can wrap it in a `$timeout` which will make sure it runs after the content has been rendered by angular.

Comment: What would you suggest instead? Scrapping this and using a more angular-friendly library? Which part of DOM manipulation is the problem: `replace:true`, or the splitter's DOM manipulation?

Comment: For DOM manipulation prefer doing it inside a directive

Comment: So basically, I will have to live with making my panels have a `<div>` at this scope? There are some cases where this is not really very clean. That element is not alawys a `<div>`, it's whatever the panel wants really.

Comment: Why does it mapper if it is a div or not. Directive need not render template always..  it can be retricted at attribuite level as well. ANyways did you try `$timeout(function(){ $('#container').split('horizontal');  });` What is split? some plugin

Comment: Because the left pane's top level element is a `<nav>` for example. I want the output to be like `<div><nav>...</nav><div>...</div></div>`, but it will end up with extra `<div>`s around the child panes. Right?

Comment: I will try `timeout`, but it seems like a hack. I'm really trying to get a better sense for the best way to solve the overall problem as I'm just learning Angular.

Comment: timeout is not a hack, it is a hack if you give delay, but you don't in this case. You just need to do it asynchronously angular pushes timeout queues (for a reason) in the end so it runs later. Put the logic in a directive and access it via element. Set the priority lower than others..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you I would do it the other way around, like this:

View:

```
<div my-splitter="vertical" class="container">
  <left-pane my-splitter-split></left-pane>
  <right-pane></right-pane>
</div>
```

Directive:

```
app.directive('mySplitter', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
      ctrl.orientation=attrs.mySplitter;
    },
    controller: function($element){
      this.split = function(){
        var orientation= this.orientation;
        $element.split({
          orientation: orientation
        });
      }
    }
  };
});

app.directive('mySplitterSplit', function(){
  return {
    require: '^mySplitter',
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, splitterCtrl) {
        splitterCtrl.split(); 
      }
  };
});
```

### [Working Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/dXVTdySEy4HdrTjP4s8D?p=preview)

Comment: The problem is that the panes haven't yet been evaluated by Angular. So at the time `split()` is called, the child elements are `<left-pane>`, so the splitter manipulates DOM elements that have yet to be removed / replaced.

Comment: @tenfour what I'm suggesting is to create a directive that should be used in the container, this should work.

Comment: @tenfour if you want set a plunker with an example working with jQuery (no angular) and I will show you how I think that you should convert it with angular

Comment: I added a plunker with a minimal repro of the issue.

Comment: No, you're thinking of `ng-include` attributes I think. Your example will error, saying it cannot load `'leftPane.html'`

Comment: In fact, for this reason, I have decided to just pre-load relevant html templates before angular bootstrap, and ditch `templateUrl`, as that seems to be the problem. Thanks for your help; still learning every day !

Comment: @tenfour I just updated my answer, please have a look at this: http://plnkr.co/edit/dXVTdySEy4HdrTjP4s8D?p=preview

Comment: Ahh that's a cool way to do this. I feel like it's also more semantically clear to specify the split panels like this too. Thanks a million!

Comment: @tenfour I must admit that it's a bit sad to have to do it this way, but the problem (as I'm sure that you already noticed) is that there is no way to know for certain when the nested directives have been rendered from the container directive... But this solution is still reasonably good. Thanks for this question! I've also learned a few things! ;)

Answer (score 3):

Note that the `link` function (unlike `controller` creation) is called *after* all children have been created and linked. So simply put your splitter code in the parent directive's `link` function.

For more information on order of execution, consider [this very helpful blog post](http://jasonmore.net/angular-js-directives-difference-controller-link/). Scroll down to "But why?!?", and you will find:

```
parent (compile)
..child 1 (compile)
....child 1 a (compile)
....child 1 b (compile)
..child 2 (compile)
....child 2 a (compile)
....child 2 b (compile)
parent (controller)
parent (pre-link)
..child 1 (controller)
..child 1 (pre-link)
....child 1 a (controller)
....child 1 a (pre-link)
....child 1 a (post-link)
....child 1 b (controller)
....child 1 b (pre-link)
....child 1 b (post-link)
..child 1 (post-link)
..child 2 (controller)
..child 2 (pre-link)
....child 2 a (controller)
....child 2 a (pre-link)
....child 2 a (post-link)
....child 2 b (controller)
....child 2 b (pre-link)
....child 2 b (post-link)
..child 2 (post-link)
parent (post-link)
```

(Note that *post-link* is the same as default `link`.)

**UPDATE**

You are using a controller for your container element. Change it to a directive instead, and all will be well!

Comment: I did not find this to be the case. Even when I make the outer container a directive, and call `split()` in `link:`, the children have not been processed yet and appear as `<left-pane>` etc.

Comment: @tenfour Can you [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) it up, for us to fiddle around with? Or is it too much code?

Comment: I'll work something up later tonight; gotta run. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I edited the question to include a plunker demonstrating the issue. Actually it only repros when using `templateUrl`; the behavior works fine if I use a literal template with `template:`.

Comment: @tenfour I am guessing that the asynchronous nature of having to fetch the template is not considered in the Angular execution order. Meaning that the execution order is not guaranteed. In that case, you need to synchronize explicitly :/